# Metal Command Buffer addCompletedHandler with async/await

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, metal

I am trying to enqueue some work on the GPU and await its completion like this:

```
// ... enqueue work ...

async let result = withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { _ in
        continuation.resume(with: Result.success((/* ... */)))
    }
}

commandBuffer.commit()

return await result
```

But the completion handler is never called. Outside of the `withCheckedContinuation` the completion handler is called as expected (with or without `commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()`).

How can I combine Metal rendering with async/await?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out:

```
return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { _ in
        continuation.resume(returning: /* ... */)
    }

    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

The difference is putting the `commit` statement inside the continuation block.